# How to extract email subjects using the Google mail audit API without using FULL_MESSAGE?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-audit-api

When doing an email dump of a user's account using the Google Mail Audit API I have been able to extract the subject data only if I use FULL_MESSAGE when making the request. However, this does downloads much more than what I need (attachments, mail bodies etc..). All I want is the ***To***, ***Cc***, ***Bcc*** and ***From*** information and the ***subject*** line for each email.

Using the HEADERS_ONLY option in the request gives all this information except for the subject info. Is it possible for subject line data to be added to the HEADERS_ONLY extraction output?

Comment: have you tried Pop3Client for this purpose? it gives better result for me

Comment: You mean a separate Pop3 client program? No I would rather use a more programmatic method.

Comment: Pop3Client is a .dll file by referencing it you can easily access the inbox mail content. you can download it from http://www.nodevice.com/dll/Pop3_dll/item13977.html#.U89EQajohi0

Comment: Using linux not MS Windows.

Comment: Sorry that was not mentioned in the question, am using Windows

Comment: Also I would rather use a supported Google API since Google will ensure it works.